# How to access variables of a PHP file inside Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel

I have a PHP file called `custom.php`
I have few arrays inside it which I want to access inside my Blade file in @foreach. What is the best way that I can access the variables inside that file?

Comment: you mean to say pass data from `controller` to `view` ?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... did you read the official doc ? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: i know how to pass data from controller to view, I have a case where I have a seperate php file in a folder say "config/custom.php" and I want to access all variables inside that file in my view @DevsiOdedra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within Laravel you can access the config variables by using the config() method. This can also be used within the blade files

For example inside your blade file:

```
{{config('custom.VARIABLE_NAME')}}
```

source: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration